# Records that have not been accessed by a different table

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a users table, videos table and actions table. When a user views a video, an actions record gets created with both their ids and some information. I want to get the Y videos not accessed by X users.

Users table

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|         ID          |       Name       |      account_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          1          |       user 1     |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          2          |       user 2     |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          3          |       user 3     |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Videos table

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|         ID          |       Name       |     account_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          1          |       video 1    |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          2          |       video 2    |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          3          |       video 3    |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Actions table

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|         user_id     |       video_id   |     account_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          1          |       3          |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          1          |       2          |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          3          |       1          |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          3          |       2          |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Desired Output:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         user name   |       video name |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          user 1     |       video 1    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          user 2     |       video 1    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          user 2     |       video 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          user 2     |       video 3    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          user 3     |       video 3    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Edit: I think is worth mentioning that there is also a foreign key attached to all of the columns called account_id. for the example we'll assume they all have the same account_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9931ca7ad06aa76ab039b653409931df)

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    v.name
FROM
    users u CROSS JOIN videos v
WHERE (u.id, v.id) NOT IN (
     SELECT user_id, video_id FROM actions
)
```

**Note**: This expected result seems really unhandy. On bigger data sets you may get a really huge output!

First you have to create a `CROSS JOIN` which joins every `user` record agains every `video` record. Afterwards you can filter the existing combinations using the `action` table.

Comment: do you mean I should query the cross joins first and then make a second query against the actions table? wouldn't that perform slower?

Comment: No, I would do it as shown :) First taking the actions data sets and exclude them from a cross join. Here you can see the order of execution: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b84142dfe08c45af2b323a839cc222d9